# How do I divide a page into 3 sections using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have a question here, I don't exactly know how to do the following, which is to divide it into 3 sections. I can show you an example of how I want it look like, I just want to know how to divide it into 3 sections.

[image: example]

```css
<style>
    * {
        margin: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    html {
        height: 100%;
        background-color: yellow;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    body {
        height: 100%;
        background-color: #ddd;
    }
    #header {
        height: 10%;
        border-bottom: 3px solid red;
    }
    h2, h3 {
        text-align: center;
    }
    #wrap {

    }
    .window { 
    
    }
    .pane { 

     }
    #window1 {
          
    }
    #window2 {
```

```html
<body>
<div id="header"><h2>Header</h2></div>

<div id="wrap">
    <div id="window1" class="window" >
        <h3>Window 1</h3>
        <p>
            Helloo
        </p>
    </div>
    
    <div id="window2" class="window">
        <h3>Window 2</h3>
        <div id="pane1" class="pane">
            Pane 1
        </div>
        <div id="pane2" class="pane">Pane 2</div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Try something first. If something specific isn't working then come here and try to find answer. See [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/jpat82792/zb6gnc9y/12/

**html**

### Header

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="window1" class="window" >
        <h3>Window 1</h3>
        <p>
            Helloo
        </p>
    </div>

    <div id="window2" class="window">
        <h3 class="window-banner">Window 2</h3>
        <div id="pane1" class="pane">
            Pane 1
        </div>
        <div id="pane2" class="pane">Pane 2</div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

**css**

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
html {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: yellow;
    overflow: hidden;
}
body {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #ddd;
}
#header {
    height: 10%;
    border-bottom: 3px solid red;
}
h2, h3 {
    text-align: center;
}
#wrap {
height: 100%;
position: relative;

}
.window-banner{
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}
.window { 
  width:50%;
  position:relative;
  float:left;
  height:100%;

}
.pane { 
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  height: 50%;
  text-align: right;
 }
 #pane1{
   border-bottom:1px dashed;
 }
#window1 {
      border-right:1px solid;
}
#window2 {
  border-left:1px solid;
}
```

I mocked up this fiddle which basically achieves your reference image. But before you TLDR this post, keep reading as this can save you a bunch of time.

1. When you have a design you want to execute do everything you know how to do first. You did a good job of this with the fiddle.
2. Then start inspecting the dom using your favorite browser. Determine how large the parent elements are. If they are too small you will end up with scrunched content, or clipped content. If those are happening, start by making the parent elements larger. In your code's case, it was #wrap was not filling the available space. So adding height:100%; fixed that.
3. Get the content blocks in the right place. So take the panes and get them to fill the proper amounts of space.
4. Now that everything is the right size and position worry about the text content. So get the panes pushed to the right, and get the window to center without displacing the pane. Here I had to research and found a great article about how to do this. I used a simple google search "how to center an absolutely positioned element" and was led to this [gem](https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/horizontal-centering-of-an-absolute-element/)
5. Then I added borders to the windows and first pane to achieve the border effects.

Now why did I type all that out? Hopefully my process helps you see what you can do next time when faced with a daunting problem. Take it piece by piece. Layout first, then the details.

The more you code, and research the conceptual models that each language uses the better your will get. Build a strong foundation and you will be able to knock these things out in no time flat. Best of luck.

Comment: Oh man, thank you so much, didn't mean for you to do all for me, but thanks a lot. I will to try to learn how you did it then :D cheers